# Is there a continuation to the "Oblivion Island" movie?

Tags: oblivion-island

I really liked *Oblivion Island: Haruka and the Magic Mirror*. I wonder if there's a second part to it, or something derived from it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find anything related to it. Even its own website (the English version at least) doesn't mention anything like that. It could be that the movie, despite receiving several awards, simply wasn't profitable enough to warrant a sequel.

http://www.oblivionisland.com/

Answer (score 0):

The movie was great but there hasn't been any sequel